# count lines matching string in each subdirectory and their subdirectories

Tags: bash, grep, find

In each subdirectory of my current directory, I would like to print the number of line-matches against a string for all files in the subdirectory and its subdirectories.

For example, if I have

```
cat /folder/a/file1.txt
test
x
x

cat /folder/a/file2.txt
x
test
x
test

cat /folder/b/c/file3.txt
x
test
x
```

I want to see the number of occurrences of `test` in `/folder` and all it's subdirectories. One line per directory. Expected output:

```
/folder: 4
/folder/a: 3
/folder/b: 1
/folder/b/c: 1
```

Comment: If any of the existing answers solves your problem, please consider accepting it via the checkmark. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another hack at it; it abuses stderr to print the results, because it uses stdout to capture the recursive totals from any subdirectories.

```
function countdirhelper {
  count=0
  string=$1
  for f in *
  do
    if [ -f "$f" ]
    then
      add=$(grep -c -- "$string" "$f")
    elif [ -d "$f" ]
    then
      add=$(cd "$f"; countdirhelper "$string")
    fi
    count=$((count + add))
  done
  printf "%s: %d\n" "$PWD" "$count" >&2
  printf %d "$count"
}

function countdir {
  countdirhelper "$1" > /dev/null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following bash script seems to work on your input case, except that it prefixes `./` to each result:

```
find . -type f |\
(
  while read FN
  do
    echo "`dirname $FN`"
    grep test "$FN" | wc -l
  done
) |\
(
  unset CTR
  declare -A CTR
  while read DN
  do
    read AA
    while [ "$DN" != "." ]
    do
      PN=${CTR[$DN]}
      [ "$PN" == "" ] && PN=0
      CTR[$DN]=$((PN+AA))
      DN="`dirname "$DN"`"
    done
  done
  for DN in "${!CTR[@]}"
  do
    echo "$DN: ${CTR[$DN]}"
  done
) | sort
```